When precisely can you spend a Luck Point?
The Lucky Origin Feat indicates you can occasionally give yourself advantage and impose disadvantage.

Advantage. When you roll a d20 for a D20 Test, you can spend 1 Luck Point to give yourself Advantage on the roll.
Disadvantage. When a creature rolls a d20 for an attack roll against you, you can spend 1 Luck Point to impose Disadvantage on that roll. (2024 PHB 5e p.201)

Can the Luck Point be spent when the numerical value of the D20 test is known to the player?
Further reading, the rules glossary describes Advantage:

Advantage  If you have Advantage on a D20 Test, roll two d20s, and use the higher roll. A roll can’t be affected by more than one
Advantage, and Advantage and Dis- advantage on the same roll cancel
each other. See also chapter 1(“D20 Tests"). (2024 PHB p.360)

And then referencing chapter 1 D20 Tests, it reads:

ROLL TWO D20s, When a roll has Advantage or Disadvantage, roll a second d20 when you make the roll. Use the higher of the two rolls if
you have Advantage, and use the lower roll if you have Disadvantage.
For example, if you have Disadvantage and roll an 18 and a 3, use the
3. If you instead have Advantage and use those numbers, use an 18.
(2024 PHB p.12)


What research have you done? What trouble are you having finding the answer yourself? In what way is the situation unclear to you?

@dopplegreener What research? I literally cited the relevant rule text. In what way is it unclear to me? It literally says “can the luck point be spent when the numerical value is known to the player”

Please be patient and wait for the book to be officially released. Edition changes often enough lead to quality control issues

I’m voting to close this question because it asks about unreleased content that is liable to change.

@except liable to change? The book has been released, I literally cite the page number in the actual book.

@AmethystWizard And? That really doesn't mean anything to me; WotC could do whatever they want. Fielding questions on unreleased content invites partial and incorrect answers and drastically shifs the social dynamic (and pressures) of who can answer a question and how.

@AmethystWizard No, the book is not yet released. A few advance copies have been released, which might, if someone at Wizards spots a huge glaring error now( Unlikely, but possible), result in the first run being recalled, pulped and replaced with a different version, with a delayed proper release.

@AmethystWizard Whether or not they actually change the rule has no bearing on my belief that questions about unreleased rules are both fragile and socially pressuring. You can disagree, but there's no value in either one of us going "I told you so" on an actual release

The rules are released, they are available to the public in the same way as most other material that is referenced.

@AmethystWizard "The rules are released, they are available to the public in the same way as most other material that is referenced." I can go to the bookstore and buy 2014 D&D. I cannot  buy 2024 D&D at that bookstore. It is simply untrue that these books are available in the same way.

I am surprised by the difference in considering this question and Do the D&D 5e 2024 rules let you choose to fail a saving throw? Why this should be closed while the other has a really positive response and remains open?

@Eddymage Well, I voted to close that too so

@Exempt-Medic Yep, I imagined that! :-D Actually, I voted to close also that one initially, since few to no people can answer, but it seems that's fine. But again, the difference in receiving the 2 posts is big...

I'm just confused by the question. Are you asking "Can I roll the d20, see the result, spend a luck point to get advantage, and then roll the second d20, hoping that it is higher? Or, do I  need to spend it before I roll anything and then just roll with advantage?"

Reviewing these comments, I will note that something being difficult to answer just because the 'books haven't been officially released' is not a valid reason to close a question. It just means that it's harder to answer the question. As was indicated, some folks received advanced copies, for all we know they have the tools to answer the question that not everyone else does. Closing this question simply because the book hadn't been officially released would be akin to closing a question because someone is asking about a rulebook no longer in publication.

Before the roll
The changes to Lucky being that it allows you to create Advantage or impose Disadvantage force the player to review the applicable 2024 rules for Advantage/Disadvantage, which state:

When a roll has either Advantage or Disadvantage, roll a second d20 when you make the roll. Use the higher of the two rolls if you have Advantage, and use the lower roll if you have Disadvantage. For example, if you have Disadvantage and roll an 18 and a 3, use the 3. If you instead have Advantage and roll those numbers, use the 18.

As highlighted above, the application of Advantage/Disadvantage obligates both dice being rolled simultaneously which can't happen if the roll is sequential.
The previous version of Lucky clearly allowed players to choose to spend their luck point after seeing the roll,

You can choose to spend one of your luck points after you roll the die, but before the outcome is determined.

but that language is notably absent in the revised feat (on the plus side, you can get a lot more luck points per day).
Thus, the determination must be made before you roll.
